# Webtest execution time much longer when in load test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

I made a simple WebPerformanceTest in VS2012 which is just logging in and doing some basic jobs on the website. When ran, this test is only running for about a second or two.

Now, I made a load test, containing only this one webtest with a `Constant` load for 5 minutes and the mode is `based on the number of virtual users`. And here comes the funny part: No matter how much users I assign to this load test the number of tests executed is always the same as the number of users assigned. I also tried raising the load test execution time giving me the same result: `one test = 5 minutes per user`, whereas it only took the webtest about 1-2 seconds to execute.

Does anyone have any idea why the test is taking way longer (300 times) in the load test? What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: The machine is a Windows Server 2008 R2 with 4 cores @ 3.00ghz and 8 GB RAM

Here's some images of the settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your configuration. Can you post your `Run Settings` and `Scenario Settings`? Post them as images.

Comment: +1 Check your test/run settings if somehting wrong is not activated : intellitrace, aspnet profiler, logs...

Comment: I surely wouldn't be asking this question if I knew what has and what has not to be activated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the Run Duration: 5:00

You've set each test to run for five minutes. So basically it runs through the test then sits their idle for the rest of the time, closes the tests and then reports back to you that it took 5 minutes. You won't see any difference unless you change this setting or create a test that could take longer than 5 minutes to run.